# Create table statement and add condition to replace None values with NULL in IMPALA

Tags: conditional-statements, impala, create-table

Bellow is my create table statement.
Some values are coming as "None" from the data source and want to add a condition to my CREATE TABLE statement to check if a value coming in equal "None" replace it with NULL. Is that possible with Impala without having an intermediate table and then ETL the data to the final TABLE with CASE STATMENT

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer_db.customers_table(
`customer_id` BIGINT NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
`ts` BIGINT NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
`customer_name` STRING NULL DEFAULT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, ts)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (`ts`)(PARTITION VALUE = 0)
STORED AS KUDU
```

Comment: How are you feeding the table?  There are many tools that permit some changes on the fly before push the data to the sink (Impala in this particular case) like Flume, Sqoop, Spark, Nifi, even Kafka.

Comment: Python script run by Nifi processor since connecting to that service is not supported yet by Nifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Import your data as CSV.
Use Notepad++ to replace none to null
Import it
https://docs.cloudera.com/machine-learning/cloud/import-data/topics/ml-loading-csv-data-into-an-impala-table.html

Try using create table as select query

None is data it cannot be converted to null via create table command
So just import data as is in temp table

Then use create table as select columns then replace column with
None to null in select query

CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] db_name.]table_name
[PARTITIONED BY (col_name[, ...])]
[SORT BY ([column [, column ...]])]
[COMMENT 'table_comment']

- [ROW FORMAT row_format]
  [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('key1'='value1', 'key2'='value2', ...)]
- [STORED AS ctas_file_format]
  [LOCATION 'hdfs_path']
- ```
  [CACHED IN 'pool_name' [WITH REPLICATION = integer] | UNCACHED]
  ```

  [TBLPROPERTIES ('key1'='value1', 'key2'='value2', ...)]
  AS
  select_statement

Comment: Replace is select replace('hello world','world','earth');
+------------------------------------------+
| replace('hello world', 'world', 'earth') |
+------------------------------------------+
| hello earth                              |
+------------------------------------------+

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have `100s` of tables and i was hoping to not have an intermediate tables because that will add more complexity for `debugging` purposes. if I could get the data from API source, make some treatment on the fly and insert it in the table that would be preferable. exactly for `INT` columns that I know for fact that they're integers but some come as `"None`".

Comment: Impala is great at detecting `"12"` even it does have quote and the destination column is an `INT` type column it does not throw an error and insert it as `INT` - `12`. was hoping I could do the same for `"None"` values, turn it to `NULL` and the `INT` column will take it because in the create statement I made it as it could be `NULL`.

Comment: Most Programming language transform string to int based on data type of column.That  is part of export or import where "12" is getting converted to 12. But None to Null is different.since you are getting data from api just place some transformation there.  Why don't you dump data as CSV and use notepad++ to  replace none to null or empty and then import it.https://docs.cloudera.com/machine-learning/cloud/import-data/topics/ml-loading-csv-data-into-an-impala-table.html

Comment: @mongotop mark it as answer if you think editing  in notepad++and import it  is the best idea

Comment: I ended up having an intermediate table in parquet and then use the `INSERT INTO table_name_stage SELECT CAST(case statement to check the value None END, DataType) FROM table_name_final`.